# phpmyadmin - root has rights but can't create a database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My problem is that I'm logged into phpmyadmin as root user and in "Users Accounts" he has "ALL PRIVILEGES" but nevertheless I cannot create a new database or create a new User..

User accounts - root:
[image: User accounts - root]

Trying to create new database:

[image: Trying to create new database]

I do not know how to fix this..

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

(I tried it without Chrome too..)

Comment: Can you create databases from my MySQL console itself?

Comment: I do not know hot it works..

Comment: create database name; as Referenz https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-database.html&ved=2ahUKEwiC2fHR0OTkAhVIYVAKHerpAEYQFjAQegQIAxAC&usg=AOvVaw1Wbd7orxLkBMAc81x5o5EZ

Comment: Ahh, thanks. But at the moment I have another problem.. I cannot get into the mysql console.. ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I tried for testing to stop mysql, but phpmyadmin works fine.. As if mysql wasn't stopped. But: [ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.


I really do not know the issue tbh..Creating tables also works fine...

Comment: Are you connecting via `localhost`?  Or TCP/IP?

Comment: No, with a ssh connection